# How to calculate total hits

Tags: java, distinct

I am parsing several log files and searching for a particular String in them.
I look through each line, once I find the string I create a Map with the String and a text as key.
Like `Map result = new HashMap(); result.put("Report Page", line.substring(60));`
I then add these Maps to a list and I interate through the list and display my table.

What I want is, to give out the number of times the string occured in the files.

Desired output :
Name   Value   Occurences.
...
...
...

Could someone please help?
(Note :This is not a homework project.)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
Map result = new HashMap();
if(line.contains("Parm Name/Value:REPORT_PAGE")){
 result.put("Report Page", line.substring(60));
}
rows.add(result);

Comment: I'm assuming this is Java? It's going to be best to tag with the language you're using otherwise people won't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, I hope I got you right.

You're currently hashing some string (whose meaning I don't understand) to the substring itself.

It also seems, for some reason, that you create a map for each line.
Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Anyway, what I think you want to do is to create a hash map which maps strings to integers.

Please paste a more complete code...

Comment: I have multiple lines in a file. I am searching for the key REPORT_PAGE in the file. If it exists I create a HashMap and add 'result.put("Report Page",temp.substring(60)'(I substring since I just want a part of the REPORT_PAGE contained line). I find all the occurence of the REPORT_PAGE key in the files and add each of the HashMap to a list which I then use to generate rows in a table.

Comment: Currently my table contains repeated values of the key value pair. I can make it distinct by using condition, if the map does not exist in the list, then add. My requirement is, a row for each of the distinct REPORT_PAGE should be in the table along with the number of times it occured in the file. Hope I am clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html. This the right choice for your use case.